# How do I create dynamically linked executable in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to create an executable in racket that is dynamically linked. Currently my hello world program compiles to 4MB executable. Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket  
#lang racket  

(define (extract str)  
  (substring str 4 7))  

(print (extract "the cat out of the bag"))
```

I compile it using

raco exe first.rkt

And the resulting executable is 4+ MB. So, clearly, it is statically linking the racket libraries.

-- EDIT ---

Here is the launcher code:

```
#lang racket

(require launcher/launcher)
(require racket/runtime-path)

(define-runtime-path prog-path "first.rkt")

(make-racket-launcher (list (path->string prog-path))
                      "first"
                      '())
```

It just needs to put in a separate file and executed with

```
 racket <launch-file>.rkt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of `raco exe` is meant to statically include its required modules, so it may not be what you want.  Have you looked at the [launcher](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html#%28mod-path._launcher/launcher%29) library?  It'll make an exe that includes nothing but the absolute minimum to launch your program on your local installation.

Alternatively, choose a smaller language, like `#lang racket/base`, which should produce smaller executables since it doesn't link to as many modules.

Finally, if you are on a Unix-based system, the program should already act as an executable if its executable bit (x) has been set, since you have already added the `#!/usr/bin/env` racket line at the top. This assumes that your Racket is in PATH. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried  raco distribute  ?

The documentation is here:
http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe-dist.html

Comment: thanks, but it creates the executable of the same size with additional folders for libraries, which are empty.